# Different languages in my bibliography biber problem

Tags: biblatex, biber, accents

I am starting to use biber with biblatex for my bibliography. I cite books in French and Spanish therefore several books and articles have accented letters in titles or author's names. I hadn't had any problem compiling my .bib file, which I have been using for two now, with bibtex. But now with biber there seems to be problems with some of my entries, not all though.

I am using TexShop and compile with Latex.

Here you'll find some lines from my preamble that might be relevant:

```
\usepackage[british]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

 \addbibresource{MyBib.bib}

 \usepackage[colorlinks, allcolors=blue, breaklinks]{hyperref}
  \begin{document}
  \autocite{key}

  \end{document}
```

When I run the bibtex (the graphic option is called bibtex buy I am using biber as backend)  I get the following message at the very beginning:

> "\x{fffd}" does not map to ascii at /var/folders/1t/gfg6lx791ds0hfh1hxskk8y40000gp/T/par-696675636873/cache-955b5cd96386991ca6623279060097e4c757d28e/inc/lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 932.

Trying to compile with Latex again I get the message:

> Undefined control sequence.  St\x{fffd}phanie

This argument corresponds to the author name in one of my entries. I modified the entry as shown below:

```
St{\'e}phanie
```

in my .bib (JabRef), but this does not solve the issue.

What can I do? And is there a way of finding a solution that does not involve going through my entire bibliography database changing characters one by one?

Comment: Biber should be able to do this reencoding for you: Take a document that `\nocite{*}`s all the entries; run `latex` on it so a `.bcf` is created; then `biber -output_encoding=UTF-8 --output_format=bibtex <yourfile>.bcf` should output a file called `<yourfile>_biber.bib`.

Comment: Also: are you using traditional pdfTeX or XeTeX/LuaTeX as the engine?  The former probably requires an explicit setting of `fontenc`, `inputenc` (I recommend `[T1]{fontenc} and `[utf8]{inputenc}` unless you need something particular), and then loading the appropriate options for `biblatex`; the latter means you are using `fontspec`.

Comment: @jon Thanks for the comments. 1. When you tell me to biber -output .... Do I need to do this from the terminal?. Also I have hundreds of refs, is there really no other way of correcting my .bib in a less tedious manner rather than \nociting every single key? Finally, what you suggest is that I replace my .bib by the one generated in the way you say?

Comment: @I-G The `\nocite{*}` command *does* nocite all your `.bib` entries: the * is like a wildcard.  So you don't need to enter each key manually.

Comment: I can post as an answer if you think this will be a viable solution.  I didn't do so earlier because I wasn't sure if you wanted a converted `.bib`.  My advice would be to use a UTF8 `.bib` file if you can use Biber most of the time, and then use biber to convert to an ASCII version (with {\'a}cc{\`e}nts, etc.) when BibTeX is required.  That way you only need to maintain one `.bib` file.

Comment: @moewe -- Done.  (This time with, hopefully, a more meaningful answer.)

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing is easily solved if you are using `biber`. As it uses UTF-8 by default, there is good reason to use the same encoding in your `bib` file.  That is, to use `é` rather than the traditional (Bib)TeX method of writing `{\'e}`.

Of course, if you ever need to use BibTeX on the existing `.bib` file, you'll run into problems if it is UTF-8.  However, `biber` can easily fix that for you:

```
biber --tool --output_encoding=ascii inputfile.bib
```

This will produce a file called `inputfile_biber.bib`, which should be ready for use with traditional BibTeX.

In the case above, it looks like `biber` is feeding you a `.bbl` that is UTF-8, but your document is using the traditional `OT1` encoding, which has little to recommend it nowadays.  For most Latin-alphabet-based documents that rely on the pdfTeX engine (i.e., compiling your document with `latex` or `pdflatex`), I recoomend you use:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

(This problem shouldn't normally have arisen if you use XeTeX (`xelatex`) or LuaTeX (`lualatex`) to compile your document...)